# How to make an HTML website interactive so that when the user clicks the delete button it changes for all users, even when you reload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I made a table in HTML, and I added a delete button so that it deletes the last recorded row in the table.

The delete button works but when I refresh the page the edits are gone, and everything is back to the original state.

How can I make it so that when the user edits the page it changes permanently?

This is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/objcLfxd/#&togetherjs=9ai74rb5DH

If that doesn't work:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: candara, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;
  color: #1b1186;
}

#DELETE {
  background-color: #1b1186;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#DELETE:hover {
  background-color: #ff4625;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: #1b1186;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px #cccccc;
  font-family: candara, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #fff06d;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

table {
  border: 5px, #1b1186
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='userhome.html';">Home</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='settings.html';">Settings</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='userhome.html';">Add Hours</button>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          var table = $('#HOURTABLE').DataTable();
          $('#HOURTABLE tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
              if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                  $(this).removeClass('selected');
              }
              else {
                  table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                  $(this).addClass('selected');
              }
          });
      });
      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="checkEdits()">
    <table id="HOURTABLE"  contenteditable="true" class="display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Session</th>
          <th># Hours</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Organization</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>4/5/2020</th>
          <th>Tutoring</th>
          <th>It was fun</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>67</th>
          <th>4/8/2020</th>
          <th>Tutoring</th>
          <th>It was interesting</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
      <br>
      <button ondblclick="row()"> 
      Delete Row 
      </button> 
      <script> 
        var x = document.getElementById("HOURTABLE").rows.length;
        
         function row() { 
            
           // delete row (index-0). 
           document.getElementById("HOURTABLE").deleteRow(1);
             
         }
      </script>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One way of doing this is to have your table data in a database and using an api like spring boot and have a function to delete an entry. As far as I know, there's no way to do this without a backend.

Comment: You could try and do this with localStorage, yet this would be similar toa cookie. MEaning that when you delete a row, you could store the change. No one else would see this change though. As has been already suggested, you'd have to have centrally stored data. This can be a a flat file, like CSV, TXT, or JSON and as complex as a Database like SQL. You also need a server side scripting language that can manipulate the data via requests from JavaScript or HTML. There are MANY now that you can choose from. Consider which you are most comfortable with and use that.

Answer (score 2):

first, if you want to show dynamic content you must use database, there is no other way.
second, if you want to make your content change in real-time you must use firebase, websocket or any other technology

Answer (score 1):

In this example I am using the localstorage, and I have created some functions so that you can handle the data.

```
<html>

<head>
  <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='userhome.html';">Home</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='settings.html';">Settings</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='userhome.html';">Add Hours</button>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="HOURTABLE" contenteditable="true" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Session</th>
        <th># Hours</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Organization</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body-container">


    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>
    <br>
    <button ondblclick="deleteRowSelected()">Delete Row</button>

    <script>

      function getData() {

        let local = localStorage.getItem('data');

        if (local == null) {

          local = setData();

        }

        return JSON.parse(local);

      }

      function setData(data = null) {

        if (data == null) {
          data =
            [
              {
                session: 1,
                hours: 4,
                date: '4/5/2020',
                organization: 'Tutoring',
                description: 'It was fun'
              },
              {
                session: 2,
                hours: 67,
                date: '4/8/2020',
                organization: 'Tutoring',
                description: 'It was interesting'
              }
            ];

        }

        const textData = JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage.removeItem('data');
        localStorage.setItem('data', textData);
        return textData;


      }

      function generateRow(row) {

        return `
            <tr data-session="${row.session}">
              <th>${row.session}</th>
              <th>${row.hours}</th>
              <th>${row.date}</th>
              <th>${row.organization}</th>
              <th>${row.description}</th>
            </tr>`;

      }

      function deleteRow(session) {

        const data = getData();
        let newArray = [];

        data.forEach(element => {


          if (element.session !== session) {

            newArray.push(element);
          }
        })
        console.log(newArray);
        setData(newArray);
        load();

      }
      function load() {

        const data = getData();
        const container = $('.body-container');
        container.html('');
        if (container.length > 0) {
          data.forEach(row => {

            container.append(generateRow(row));

          })

        } else {
          container.appent('<tr>empty</tr>');
        }

      }
      var x = document.getElementById("HOURTABLE").rows.length;

      function deleteRowSelected() {

        const row = $('.body-container').find('tr.selected');
        if (row.length == 0) {
          alert('you must select a row');
        } else {
          row.remove();
          deleteRow(row.data('session'));
        }

      }


      $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#HOURTABLE').DataTable();
        $('#HOURTABLE tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
          if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
          }
          else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
          }
        });

        load();
      });

    </script>

  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example assumes you are using PHP and that a PHP Script, called `delsessions.php`, is setup on your Web Server. This script will accept an Array of IDs via HTTP POST. It will then update a SQL Database and remove rows from a table associated with the Session IDs passed to it.

This also assumes there is script or API that provides the table data from the same Database table.

```js
$(function() {
  var table = $('#HOURTABLE').DataTable();

  function href(el) {
    window.location.href = $(el).data("href");
  }

  function delRows() {
    var sessions = [];
    $(".selected").each(function(i, el) {
      sessions.push($(el).children().eq(0).text());
    })
    table.rows(".selected").remove().draw();
    console.log("Delete Sessions", sessions);
    $.post("delsessions.php", {
      ids: sessions
    });
  }

  $(".btn[data-href]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    href(this);
  });

  $(".delete-row").click(delRows);

  $('#HOURTABLE tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: candara, monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1000px;
  color: #1b1186;
}

#DELETE {
  background-color: #1b1186;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#DELETE:hover {
  background-color: #ff4625;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: #1b1186;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px #cccccc;
  font-family: candara, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #fff06d;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

table {
  border: 5px, #1b1186
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<button class="home btn" data-href="userhome.html">Home</button>
<button class="settings btn" data-href="settings.html">Settings</button>
<button class="add-hours btn" data-href="userhome.html">Add Hours</button>
<button class="delete-row btn">Delete Row</button>
<table id="HOURTABLE" contenteditable="true" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Session</th>
      <th># Hours</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Organization</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>4/5/2020</th>
      <th>Tutoring</th>
      <th>It was fun</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>67</th>
      <th>4/8/2020</th>
      <th>Tutoring</th>
      <th>It was interesting</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

When the user selects, via `click` the various Rows and clicks "Delete Row" button, the Datatable will be updated, removing those rows, and the IDs for those rows will be posted to the PHP. The script will then delete the relative rows from the database. When the User returns to the site or reloads the site, the database table will no longer contain the rows and will not present them when constructing the HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do that without a back-end like PHP, node.js, firebase...

You can do a hack using localStorage but changes will remain only while user dosn't delete browser data.